# Выделить модальное окно полужирным шрифтом и выделить цветом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно в модальном окне выделить текст полужирным шрифтом и выделить желтым цветом:

```
if($('#causezpzId').val() == 25){        
    strMessage1 = (typeof strMessage1 !== 'undefined') ? strMessage1 : 'Проверьте кодировку'; 
    return !!confirm( strMessage1 );         
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В `alert`, `prompt` и `confirm` нельзя форматировать текст, добавлять какие-либо `html`-теги, только текст.

Если так уж хотите стилизовать  свои уведомления, то пишите собственные кастомные уведомления или используйте какую-нибудь `js`-библиотеку. Знаю, что есть плагин для `EasyUI`, но нет смысла подключать эту тяжелую библиотеку только ради кастомных уведомлений.

В гугле нашел [такой плагин](https://blogjquery.ru/zamena-standartnogo-alert-prompt-confirm-stilizaciya-alert/), сам не проверял, но возможно вам такое решение подойдет, ну или ищите что-то подобное.

Comment: Попробовав несколько таких плагинов например ... return !!lnv.confirm( strMessage1);. Выяснилось что он работает не совсем правильно. Т.е. при lnv.confirm он все равно выполняется где-то через 1 сек даже не нажимая ничего, а стандартный confirm только при нажатии ок.